# parsing out duplicate barcodes in a separate line

Tags: grep

I've got the following data I need to parse out the duplicates from column1 into a separate file,

For example,

```
21288003132541:cr
21288003267289:fr
21288003758683:ph
21288003758683:tag
21288003758683:sel
```

I want to take out this line `21288003758683:tag` into a separate file, my output needed is separate files for any uniq line with subsequent files with any duplicates.

So for example file 1

```
21288003132541:cr
21288003267289:fr
21288003758683:ph
```

file 2

```
21288003758683:tag
```

file 3

```
21288003758683:sel
```

Hope this makes sense

Thanks

Comment: are the duplicates guaranteed to all be next to each other?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
[ $# -ge 1 ] && [ -f "$1" ] || exit
while read oneline;do
    for onecode in $oneline;do
        let count=1
        outfile="output.$count"
        [ -f $outfile ] || touch $outfile
        while grep "${onecode%:*}" $outfile >/dev/null;do
            let count+=1
            outfile="output.$count"
            [ -f $outfile ] || touch $outfile
        done
        echo "$onecode" >>$outfile
    done
done < "$1"
```

The above code will result in several files being created, named output.1, output.2, etc. depending on how many duplicates are found. I wasn't sure if the line formatting of the output was important, or if you wanted to replace the original file when done.

Answer (score 0):

Python version using an array of dictionaries.  Note that the output order won't be preserved in this version.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import fileinput

dics = []
for line in fileinput.input():
    (a, _) = line.split(':')
    for dic in dics:
        if a not in dic:
            dic[a] = line
            break
    else:
        dics.append({a: line})

for i, dic in enumerate(dics):
    with open('file%d.txt' % (i+1), 'w') as f:
        for line in dic.values():
            f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I save the file in xx, then:

```
touch mem; num=$(wc -l xx | awk '{print $1}');
for ((i=1 ; i<= $num ; i++ )) do
n=$(sed -n ''$i'p' xx );
nn=$(echo $n | awk -F":" '{print $1}')
grep "$nn" xx  > xx1
jj=1;  aa=$(grep "$nn" mem)
if [[ -z $aa  ]] ; then
cat xx1 | while read n ; do
echo $n >> file$jj ; 
jj=$(($jj+1)) ; 
done ;fi
echo $nn >> mem; 
done
```